# Почему при редиректе выходит такая ошибка?:

Tags: php, ajax

Вот ошибка:

> index.php:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=7653817&redirect_uri=http://localhost/&response_type=code.
>   Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Вот программа на сервере — **index.php**:

```
$client_id = '5563817';
$client_secret = 'CjHNfghfDqfVJ6PrK3pa';
$redirect_url = 'http://localhost/'; 
$msgtoclient = '';

    $url = 'http://oauth.vk.com/authorize';

    $params = array(
        'client_id'     => $client_id,
        'redirect_url'  => $redirect_url,
        'response_type' => 'code'
    );

 $link = $url . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params));

 if (isset($_GET['code'])) {$msgtoclient='';} else { header('Location:'.$link);}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $result = false;
    $params = array(
        'client_id' => $client_id,
        'client_secret' => $client_secret,
        'code' => $_GET['code'],
        'redirect_url' => $redirect_url
    );

    $token = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))), true);

    if (isset($token['access_token'])) {
        $params = array(
            'uids'         => $token['user_id'],
            'fields'       => 'uid,first_name,last_name,screen_name,sex,bdate,photo_big',
            'access_token' => $token['access_token']
        );

        $userInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))), true);
        if (isset($userInfo['response'][0]['uid'])) {
            $userInfo = $userInfo['response'][0];
            $result = true;
        }
    }

    if ($result) {
$msgtoclient = $userInfo;
} else {$msgtoclient = 'sdsdsd';}
}
echo json_encode($msgtoclient) ;
```

Вот так делается запрос к **index.php**:

```
<a href='' onclick="authvkmsg();">Регистрация ВК</a>

<script>
    function authvkmsg()
    {
        $.ajax({
         url: "index.php",

         success:  function() { alert('dfdf');},
         error: function() {  alert('error'); }
     });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Добавте ваш код.

Comment: Почему ошибка AJAX-запроса говорит о `oauth.vk.com`, если вы делаете запрос к своему серверу?

Comment: @terron, потому что сначало идет запрос к вконтакте затем ответ возвращается на мой сервер а оттуда уже по идее через аjax идет уже работа с клиентом

Comment: а для $redirect_url вместо localhost какой-нить доступный из вне адрес не пробовали использовать? Мне кажется тут загвоздка. И скройте куда-нибудь $client_secret